# How does preload handled by browsers with no-cache headers?

Tags: caching, browser, preload

I'd like to speed up the initial loading of a site. It requests several API endpoints during inital render. I want to add `<link rel="preload" />` for a few of these requests to make them start loading earlier. However these API responses are not cacheable by the browser. So the question is: How the browser behaves in such case? Will it fetch the content again regardless of the preload due to the no-cache headers or it's smart enough to relize that I need exactly that preloaded content?

Answer (score 2):

So it turns out it's respecting `no-cache` headers as expected. I cannot preload such using `<link rel="preload">`. The solution is to add a few second TTL.

Comment: How did you end-up solving this? How did you add the TTL?

Comment: I simply added cache header with a few second TTL insted of no-cache.